# Returning a probability vector for predications

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using scikit-learn for classification. Is there a way to get a probability *vector* that says how confident the classifier is for its prediction? I want a vector for the entire test set, not just for a single element. Basically I need that to compute ROC curve and AUC.

Answer (score 1):

If your only goal is to get the ROC curve and AUC, checkout out `sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score` [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score).

From the docs:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
>>> y_true = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])
>>> y_scores = np.array([0.1, 0.4, 0.35, 0.8])
>>> roc_auc_score(y_true, y_scores)
0.75
```

Note that roc_auc_score is only suited for binary classification tasks -- if you're dealing with multiclass classification you'll likely have to compute separate `roc_auc_score` values for each class.

Answer (score 1):

Many classifiers have either a `decision_function` method, or a `predict_proba` method (or both) which can be used to obtain soft scores instead of hard decisions. Example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X = np.random.randn(10, 4)
>>> y = np.random.randint(0, 2, 10)
>>> from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
>>> svm = LinearSVC().fit(X, y)
>>> svm.decision_function(X)
array([-0.92744332,  0.78697484, -0.71569751, -0.19938963, -0.15521737,
        0.45962204,  0.1326111 ,  0.44614422,  0.95731802,  0.8980536 ])
```

The values, in this case, are the signed distances from the hyperplane of a linear SVM. `predict_proba` is slightly different in that it returns a matrix of probabilities, but you can get a vector of positive probabilities by indexing:

```
>>> from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
>>> lr = LogisticRegression().fit(X, y)
>>> lr.predict_proba(X)
array([[ 0.73987796,  0.26012204],
       [ 0.26009545,  0.73990455],
       [ 0.63918314,  0.36081686],
       [ 0.62055698,  0.37944302],
       [ 0.54361598,  0.45638402],
       [ 0.38383357,  0.61616643],
       [ 0.50740302,  0.49259698],
       [ 0.39236783,  0.60763217],
       [ 0.32553896,  0.67446104],
       [ 0.20791651,  0.79208349]])
>>> lr.predict_proba(X)[:, 1]
array([ 0.26012204,  0.73990455,  0.36081686,  0.37944302,  0.45638402,
        0.61616643,  0.49259698,  0.60763217,  0.67446104,  0.79208349])
```

Comment: what if I wanna return the probability of overall, should I try to find the mean between these values ?

Comment: @user3378649 I don't think "overall probability" is a well-defined concept in a conditional model. It depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

In scikit-learn, for any classification method, you can turn on `probability` option and use `predict_proba` method to get the probability of the elements for each class. For example, using famous iris dataset,

```
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import datasets

# train set
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[0::2, :2]  
Y = iris.target[0::2]

clf = svm.SVC(probability=True)
clf.fit(X, Y) 

# test set
Z = iris.data[1::2, :2]

Y_predict = clf.predict(Z)
Y_actual = iris.target[1::2]
Y_probas = clf.predict_proba(Z) # probabilities of each classification
```

Comment: Actually only `SVC` has the `probability` flag. Most other classifiers either have `predict_proba` or they don't; `SGDClassifier` has it conditionally based on its `loss` parameter.